# How to make object scroll through HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, scroll, html5-canvas

I've been trying to make objects scroll through the canvas, like when it goes down, it will come out of the top. I have got it working for the bottom and right sides, but it just gets stuck on the left and top side.
Here is what the code looks like in action
http://output.jsbin.com/gavuqo/

Here is my javascript code:

```
var count = 1;
var myGamePiece;
var myObstacle;
var myHealth;
var myScore;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(40, 40, "http://www.link", 10, 120, "image");
    myObstacle = new component(60, 60, "http://www.link", 300, 120, "image"); 
    myHealth = new component(60, 60, "http://www.link", 300, 100, "image"); 

    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 600;
        this.canvas.height = 400;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
};

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    if (type == "image") {
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = color;
    }
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.angle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360) + 0  ;
    this.speed = 1;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    

    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (type == "image") {
            ctx.drawImage(this.image, 
                this.x, 
                this.y,
                this.width, this.height);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        } 
        }

        this.newPos = function() {
if( this.x<=0 || this.x>=600){this.x = -this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);}else{    this.x += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
}
        if( this.y<=0 || this.y>=400) {this.y = -this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);}else{
        this.y += this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);}    


    }



                //myObstacle.newPos();



    this.newPosmain = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;        
    };
     this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) ||
               (mytop > otherbottom) ||
               (myright < otherleft) ||
               (myleft > otherright)) {
           crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    };
}

function updateGameArea() {
    if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle) && count==1) {
            myObstacle = new component(60, 60, "http://www.link", 300, 120, "image"); 
            count++;
            myGamePiece = new component(80, 80, "http://www.link", 10, 120, "image");



    } else {
        myGameArea.clear();
        myObstacle.update();
        //myObstacle.wallBounce();
        myObstacle.newPos();
        myHealth.update();
        myHealth.newPos();
        //myHealth.wallBounce();
        myGamePiece.newPosmain(); 
        myGamePiece.update();
    }
    if(myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle) && count==2){
        myObstacle = new component(60, 60, "http://www.link", 300, 120, "image"); 
                myGamePiece = new component(100, 100, "http://www.link", 10, 120, "image");

                count++;

}
if(myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle) && count==3){

         myGamePiece = new component(500, 500, "#", 0, 0, "image");

    myeGameArea.stop();


    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('#')";
      count=0;              

}

if(myGamePiece.crashWith(myHealth) && count==1){
                myGamePiece = new component(100, 100, "http://www.link", 10, 120, "image");
                count=0;
             count--;
}
if(myGamePiece.crashWith(myHealth) && count==2){
    myGamePiece = new component(40, 40, "http://www.link", 10, 120, "image");            
                count--;
}
if(myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle) && count==0){
            myObstacle = new component(60, 60, "http://www.link", 300, 120, "image"); 
                myGamePiece = new component(100, 100, "http://www.link", 10, 120, "image");

                count++;
}
if(myGamePiece.crashWith(myHealth) && count==0){
                myGamePiece = new component(500, 500, "http://example.com", 0, 0, "image");

}
}
function moveup() {
    myGamePiece.speedY = -2; 
}

function movedown() {
    myGamePiece.speedY = 2; 
}

function moveleft() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = -2; 
}

function moveright() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 2; 
}

function clearmove() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0; 
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Try putting your full code up on somewhere like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), or [CodePen](http://codepen.io), so we can see your code in action. We'll be able to help you a lot more that way. I say this because it looks like there is a lot going on in your code, that's not easy to debug just by looking at it. Alternatively, you can create just a single case example, without the extra fluff of your game, and with just a canvas and a moving object. If you can get it working that way you can figure out why your game is not working.

Comment: Hi, Here is a link to an output of my game http://jsbin.com/gavuqo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adjust either the x or y position to be opposite of the exit point. If it exits at the bottom then reset it to top minus diameter of the object without adjusting x, and so forth.

**In generic code:**

```
// dia = diameter of object (you may have to use different values for width/height)

if (x < -dia) x = width;
else if (x >= width) x = -dia;

if (y < -dia) y = height;
else if (y >= height) y = -dia;
```

### Example

**(click run again to change direction)**

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    x = c.width * 0.5, y = c.height * 0.5,
    dx = Math.max(2, Math.random() * 4),
    dy = Math.max(2, Math.random() * 4),
    dia = 10;

dx *= Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
dy *= Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;

(function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, dia, dia);
  
  x += dx;
  y += dy;
  
  if (x < -dia) x = c.width;
  else if (x >= c.width) x = -dia;

  if (y < -dia) y = c.height;
  else if (y >= c.height) y = -dia;
  
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
})()
```

```css
#c {border:1px solid #999}
```

```html
<canvas id=c>
```